# Soft keyboard changes the view layout when it opens in landscape

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, landscape

Why does the soft keyboard change the layout so dramatically when I swap this screen to landscape?  It works perfectly fine in portrait.  I am assuming that it has to do with the limited space, but the keyboard could still open without covering the `EditText` that spawned it.  It even inserts a `Search` button.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default Android behavior, users should be used to it.  But if you really don't want this to happen, you can put `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` in the EditText layout.

Also, the "Search" button is what you've specified in the `android:imeOptions` for the action.

Comment: Right, `imeOptions="actionSearch"` is why it says **Search**.  Otherwise it would say **Done**.  So can I do both `flagNoExtractUi` and `actionSearch`?  I am going to try `android:imeOptions="imeOptions|flagNoExtractUi"`.

Comment: `android:imeOptions="imeOptions|flagNoExtractUi"` should work fine